# execute controller method with delayed_job gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, delayed-job

I have a method inside my controller that I need execute inside delayed job method:

This is my `order controller action`:

```
class OrdersController < ApplicationController

 def create
  #code here
  order = Order.first
  Order.delay(queue: "order", priority: 1, run_at: 2.minutes.from_now).expire_order(order)
 end

 def template_expired_order(order)
  #code here
 end

end
```

This is my `order model:`

```
class Order
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps::Created
  .
  .
  .
  #delayed jobs method
  def self.expire_order(order)
   #code here
  end
end
```

**I want execute the controller method `template_expired_order(order)` when `self.expire_order(order)` method is executed or triggered or fired up.**

How can I do it?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not put model-related code in the controller, especially if you want to run it in a background job. It's not clear what template_expired_order does, but I would recommend putting it in the Order model and calling it directly on the order that gets pass into expired_order.

```
class Order
  def expire_order(order)
    order.template_expired_order
  end

  def template_expired_order
    # code
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you. My problem is that `template_expired_order` method have render a partial as: `def template_expired_order render_to_string :partial => 'job_has_expired', :locals => {:order => order}} end` I dont know if delayed_job hooks is valid for this case...

Comment: Why are you rendering a partial in a background job?

Comment: I need save this partial content on my db when delayed_job method is executed

Comment: It seems like you shouldn't need a controller for that. Is it HTML, plain text, or some other format?

Comment: Thank you, is a dynamic HTML format partial... Inside `Message.body` attribute will go the `job_has_expired` partial content